# Weights in group theory

Tags: group-theory, physics, spherical-harmonics

What are the meaning of weights in group theory?

For example consider the $SU(3)$ group and the angular momentum problem. The spherical harmonics $lm$ induce weights which result irrep. If we add two spin-1 particles we will have:

$$(2,0) \otimes (1,0) \otimes (0,0)$$

Comment: Weights are collections of eigenvalues for the action of what is called the maximal torus in a Lie group, or the Cartan subalgebra in a semisimple Lie algebra. Weight spaces are the corresponding eigenspaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is it possible to associate the spherical harmonics $lm$ with the weights?